# Start and receive intents with the same action

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to receive intents with the action VIEW

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

And I want to start other apps with intents with the same action VIEW

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But I dont't want to start my own activity. I want that the user sees the standard list of activities that can receive the intent.
How can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a chooser for your intent

`Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "randome title");`

or make your code like this

`context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "randome title"));`

Comment: Great. Didn't knew that this intent chooser existed. But the problem was that my emulator hadn't got a single app to show pdf's ;) On my mobile the chooser is coming up without explicit programming.